# Recyclerview attributes not being displayed

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new with Android Studio and having problem with setting the attributes e.g. The ID, adjust the constraints etc., simply because the attributes are not displayed in the attributes panel. I have tried deleting the recyclerview and re inserting them, restarting Android Studio, and even rebooting to no avail. I understand that I can set these attributes manually in the XML file but I would prefer to do it within the attributes panel.

[image: Screenshot with the recyclerview selected in the design layout]

Comment: goto :- File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart and select Invalidate and restart then check may be its work.

Answer (score 0):

use this  to see atributes

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:orientation="horizontal"
tools:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
tools:listitem="@layout/view_item" />
```

Answer (score 0):

At the corner of the left bottom, you can see design and text, Now you are in design mode click on text mode to get exactly what you want. 
Thanks.

And try this to make sure it is working properly
File > Invalidate Caches > Restart

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by just restarting Android Studio !!!